# How to JSON Parse URL from SharePreference With AsyncTask, Can't execute URL from SharePreference

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

How to JSON Parse URL from SharePreference With AsyncTask, Can't execute URL from SharePreference. But when URL iset Manual From Activity not from getString SharePreference result is OK.

**Save SharePreference**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Options", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();

String a = String.valueOf(obj.texta);
                    byte[] idsek64 = Base64.encode(a.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    String idsek64siap = new String(idsek64);
                    String idsekrot13 = rot13(idsek64siap);
                    String UrlSek = "https://128.60.12.111/contacts/"+idsekrot13+"/id?_s=ARLlBQWRAR";
                    editor.putString("proc",UrlSek);
                    editor.commit();
```

**Get Data From SharePreference and Proses**
The strings that I took from SharePreference, from the SharePreference String Store, are appropriate, and I proved them when I placed the Toast.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Options", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String urls = pref.getString("proc","");
if (HttpHandler.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(urls);

        } else {

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO INTERNET!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

//PROSES MYTASK EXECUTE URL
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return HttpHandler.getJSONString(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (null == result || result.contains("[]")) {
                customtoast2.show();
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray subArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
```

But when im set urls manual look like :

```
String urls ="https://128.60.12.111/contacts/curent_job/id?_s=ARLlBQWRAR"
if (HttpHandler.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            new MyTask().execute(urls);

        } else {
    ....
}
```

The results that come out will be the way I want.

If anyone helps I am very grateful.

Comment: Did you really put the url in SharePreference? Show those code

Comment: show how you put the URL into SharedPreferences.

Comment: where you save & where you retrive? show these specific codes

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman yess really, but I have updated my question

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko OK, I have updated my question. please check.

Comment: @RanjithKumar, please read my question and I have updated my question

Comment: `String b = String.valueOf(obj.texta);` Where do you use **b**?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I just wrote the wrong code here, in my project it's correct, sorry and I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong in your storing part.

```
 public class SharedPrefsActivity extends Activity {

 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyApp_Settings";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

  // Writing data to SharedPreferences
  Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("key", "some value");
  editor.commit();

  // Reading from SharedPreferences
  String value = settings.getString("key", "");
  Log.d(TAG, value);
 }
}
```

are you using this "Options" to store? or are you using two instances with two different tags? . better to use same instance of SharedPreferences or same tag 
make sure your storing is ok, good luck

Answer (score 0):

use the PrefsUtils class instead of saving it like this.

```
/**
* A pack of helpful getter and setter methods for reading/writing to {@link SharedPreferences}.
*/
final public class SharedPrefsUtils {
private SharedPrefsUtils() {}

/**
 * Helper method to retrieve a String value from {@link SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param context a {@link Context} object.
 * @param key
 * @return The value from shared preferences, or null if the value could not be read.
 */
public static String getStringPreference(Context context, String key) {
    String value = null;
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences != null) {
        value = preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
    return value;
}

/**
 * Helper method to write a String value to {@link SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param context a {@link Context} object.
 * @param key
 * @param value
 * @return true if the new value was successfully written to persistent storage.
 */
public static boolean setStringPreference(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(key)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

add below line in your activity to set into pref

`SharedPrefsUtils.setStringPreference(this,"your_key","your_value");`

to get the prefs value use

`SharedPrefsUtils.getStringPreference(this,"your_key");`

Comment: I think the problem is with the parse url not the store or reading data. Because my compilation displays TOAST with the string that I took from the sharepreference it looks absolutely right